# How to do a case-sensitive search in Preview application?

Tags: preview

Is it possible to perform a case-sensitive search in `Preview`?

For example, I'd like to find all occurrences of the text

> LAST

but not

> last

or

> Last

I tried enclosing term in double quotes to no effect:

> "LAST"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In preview there is no option for case sensitive search , but you can use the mac third party apps from ADOBE where you can get more search options like case sensitive,stemming ..etc More reference use [this](http://www.wikihow.com/Search-for-a-Word-or-Phrase-in-a-PDF-Document)